# Trying to make a Rock, Papers, Scissors program with enum in C++

Tags: c++, enums

I'm taking a C++ class, and I'm doing an assignment involving enums and random selections. My code seems to be broken. My enum keeps being seen as a int, not a char, and XCode keeps giving me Expected Identifier in the line with my enum. The game logic uses chars, not ints. How can I fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <random>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Let's play some Rock, Papers, and Scissors!\nEnter a choice to Start: R, P, or S!" << std::endl;
    char pInput;
    std::cin >> pInput;
    srand( time(NULL) );
    int cInput = rand() % 3; //Computer chooses number mapped to chars R, P, or S
    enum class RockPaperScissors { 'R', 'S', 'P' };
    if( pInput == 'R' && cInput == 'R' )
    {
        std::cout << "You tied with me!" << std::endl;
    }
    else if( pInput == 'R' && cInput == 'S' )
    {
    std::cout << "Drats! You win!" << std::endl;
    }
    else if( pInput == 'R' && cInput == 'P' )
    {
        std::cout << "Hah! Here comes the Hug of Death!" << std::endl;
    }
    else if( pInput == 'S' && cInput == 'S')
    {
        std::cout << "Looks like we tied!" << std::endl;
    }
    else if( pInput == 'S' && cInput == 'R')
    {
        std::cout << "Hah! I smashed you, so I win!" << std::endl;
    }
    else if( pInput == 'S' && cInput == 'P')
    {
        std::cout << "Drats! You win!" << std::endl;
    }
    else if( pInput == 'P' && cInput == 'P')
    {
        std::cout << "Drats! We tied!" << std::endl;
    }
    else if( pInput == 'P' && cInput == 'S')
    {
        std::cout << "Hah! I win, because I'm a scissor!" << std::endl;
    }
    else if( pInput == 'P' && cInput == 'R')
    {
        std::cout << "Drats! You gave me the Hug of Death!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is probably best answered with a link to a good documentation source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum

Comment: You do realize that the problem can be solved a lot more elegantly and with 1/4 as much code _without enums_? An integer, addition, and modulo are enough for implementing the logic, plus optionally a const char* array with 3 elements to display the names. No long chain of else ifs necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP is missing a few details to get what they want

```
enum class RockPaperScissors { 'R', 'S', 'P' };
```

Ignoring that the above does not compile, get to that in a minute, RockPaperScissors defaults to integer because the underlying type is not specified. You can change the type by declaring it after the name like this: `RockPaperScissors:char`

An enumerated type is a set of mappings of name to value. If you don't get involved and set the value, the first value starts somewhere and counts upwards. Someone with a copy of the standard can confirm whether or not this is guaranteeded to be 0 and an increment of one. I can't. The thing is, the actual values shouldn't matter. If they do, explicitly set them so no one gets a surprise.

In this case we want them to be specific characters. This could be as simple as

```
enum class RockPaperScissors:char { R = 'R', S = 'S', P = 'P' };
```

But this is stupid. It defeats the point of an enum to use enumerator names that simple. An enum should, just like a variable, explain to a reader what it represents. Otherwise we'd forget about the name; just use value and be done with it. So instead,

```
enum class RockPaperScissors:char { ROCK = 'R', SCISSORS = 'S', PAPER = 'P' };
```

Using it

```
if( pInput == RockPaperScissors::ROCK && cInput == RockPaperScissors::ROCK )
{
    std::cout << "You tied with me!" << std::endl;
}
```

Unless you have to use a class enum because it is an assignment requirement, this usage is pretty trivial and the class enum is pretty much wasted. You can simplify things, and to a bit less typing with

```
enum RockPaperScissors:char { ROCK = 'R', SCISSORS = 'S', PAPER = 'P' };
if( pInput == ROCK && cInput == ROCK )
{
    std::cout << "You tied with me!" << std::endl;
}
```

Groovy, huh?

While this meets the OP's requirement, it won't do much good.

```
srand( time(NULL) );
int cInput = rand() % 3; //Computer chooses number mapped to chars R, P, or S
```

The comment lies. No mapping is done, so

```
if( pInput == ROCK && cInput == ROCK )
```

is comparing an enum based on a char to an integer. Compiler will allow that, with a warning I hope, but the integer provided will be 0, 1, or 2. ROCK is R, or 82. The comparison will always fail. So let's get freaky with arrays (and totally ignore the fact that rand sucks. For real work, not churn out the assignment work, use c++11's random library. [Specifically std::uniform_int_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)).

```
enum RockPaperScissors:char { ROCK = 'R', SCISSORS = 'S', PAPER = 'P' };
enum RockPaperScissors rpsmap[] = 
{
    ROCK,
    SCISSORS,
    PAPER
};
enum RockPaperScissors cInput = rpsmap[rand() % 3]; //Computer chooses number mapped to chars R, P, or S
```

Now cInput is mapped to R, P, or S. Now we can meaningfully compare pInput and cInput.

But what if the user types in 'Q'? What then?

```
std::cin >> pInput;
```

Allows for all sorts of abuse. OP will have to guard that as well, and after that there is a ton of optimizing of that if/else if....

Answer (score 0):

`enum` always assigns an integer to its value starting from 0.

Use

```
pInput == S   //S without quotes
```

Or

```
pInput == 1   //Corresponding integer value
```

And pInput & cInput must be of type `enum` or `ineger`

Comment: Close, but nope. Don't have to start at zero. Don't have to be Integer.

Comment: yes, I agree.  But in this case, this is what happening.